# Retrieve popup window selection

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a popup window from which I want to retrieve a value, I want to send the value back to the page that initiated the popup window. I want to avoid using php if that's possible?
Can someone tell me if this is possible, if so can it be done with javascript? And how could I start with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
child = window.open(...)
child.callback = function(value) { ... do something with value ... }
```

In your child window, you can now call `callback` as if it was defined there:

```
callback(value);
```